# Penny for your Thoughts

Tags: cipher

<sub>I had an idea for a cipher and I don't know enough about ciphers to know if it already exists. I'd like to see how easily this is solved and if such an idea is already popularized somewhere. I have a hard time believing that nobody has ever had the idea because I'm just not that clever but I don't remember seeing it before. I've provided what I think is plenty of text to allow for breaking and tried to liven it up a bit with some flavor.</sub>

---

Prior to joining forces with Lord Hooty McOwlface - indeed, even before his Lorship's rise to power - Fakky Jim was a typical human. He was a metal worker refining zinc for the U.S. Mint to produce coins. There were a lot of special regulations he had to follow but, in general, he was just a foundry guy. He lived alone and spent most weekend picking up scrap metal to sell to his employer (for non-coinage use, obviously).

It was a fine Saturday in June when his life was changed. He was in the dump looking for scrap when he happened across a lamp. It was covered in soot and, as he tried to wipe it clean and inspect the metal quality, the lamp shook violently and shocked his hand. Fakky dropped the thing and out swarmed a dark, purplish-black cloud of lightning and laughter. In a few seconds, the cloud had solidified into the grinning face of a genie with fiery red eyes.

`VERY WELL` boomed the smoky creature inside Fakky's head, `YOU SHALL BE TESTED.`
“Tested?” asked Fakky Jim. “I thought I was supposed to get some wishes.”
`ONLY IF YOUR WISH IS TO BE TESTED AND REWARDED OR PUNISHED BASED ON YOUR PERFORMANCE.`
“But what if I –“
`LET THE TEST BEGIN`

A giant penny was suddenly floating in front of Fakky’s face. Slowly, it rotated down so he was looking at the edge. There were letters inscribed there. The penny began to rotate and reveal more characters in an apparently random sequence. He tried to move but found himself rooted to the spot. Confused, he looked back up at the genie.

`TELL ME THE MESSAGE ON THE EDGE OF THIS COIN AND YOU SHALL BE FREED AND REWARDED.`
`FAIL, AND BE FREED AND PUNISHED.`

Unfortunately, Fakky was unable to decode the coin and was turned into a cat, albeit an immortal, magical cat. His anger towards what he felt was a random punishment of the universe led him down a path of evil. How would you have fared against the same challenge? (Text on the edge of the coin is transcribed below.)

> GntS rDPSF zOc TFWdO xdzSr zHn ntS eBUIdSr aqntfIs GnqUI Pm sgJr bnOUJmFOs B mdX mBsJPm bnObFhWdE hm khadqUZ BmE EdEhDzUFE Un UgF QSPQnrJshPm UIzU zkk ldO zSF bqdBsFc dRVBk mPv vF zqF dmfzHFE hm B HqFzU bJuhM vBS UFTsJmf XIFsgFq sgBs Ozshnm nS zmZ mzsJnO rP bnmDdhudE Bmc rP EFchbzsdE DBm kPOH dOEVqd vd BSF NdU Pm B fSFzs CBssMFehFkc nG sgBs Xzq vF gBWd bnNd Un cFchbzUd B onSsJnm nG sgzs ehFMc zT B ehOzk SdTshOH okBDF GnS Ugnrd vgP gdSd fzuF UgdJq kJuFr sIzs sgzU OBUJPO lhHIU Mhud hs hT BksnHFUgdq GJsUhmf zOE QSnoFS UIBs vF rgPtkc En UghT CVs hO z kBSfFq rFOTF vF DBO mPs EdchbzsF  vd DBO mns DPmTdDqzsF  vd bzm OPU IBMkPX  sIhr fqPtOc sgd aqzWd NFm kJWJmf zOE cdzc XgP rUSVHfkFE Idqd gzWF DnOTFbSBsdE JU GBS zaPud PVS onPS onvdS Un BEc PS cdUSzDs sgd XPSkc vhMk kJUsMF mnsd OPq kPmH SFNFNCdq XgBs vd rzZ IFSF atU JU DBO mdWdq enSHds vgzs sgFZ chc IFSF hs JT ePq VT Ugd kJWJmH qBUIFq sn CF cdEhbzsFE gdqF Un sgd VmGJOhrgdc vPSj vIJbI UIdx XIn GnVHgU gdSd gBWF sItT GzS rn mnakZ BcWzODdEhs JT qzsIFS enq VT sn CF Idqd cdchbzsFE UP UIF fqFBs UzTj qFNBhOhmf CdePqd tr  Ugzs eqnN sIdrd gPmPqdc Edzc vF UzjF JmDqFzrFE EFWnsJPm UP UgBU bzVrF ePq vgJDI UgFZ fzuF Ugd kzTU etkM NFzrVSd ne EFuPUhPO  sIzU vd gFSF gJfgMZ qdrnkWd sIzs UIdrd cFzc TgBkk OPU IzWF EhdE Jm uBhO  UIzs sghr OBUJnO VmEdq HPE rgzMk IzuF B mFv aJSsI PG eqFdcnl  Bmc UgzU HPudqOlFms nG Ugd oFnokF CZ UgF oFnQMd ePq sgF oFPQkd rIBMk mns QFqhrg eSnN sgF dzSsI

Comment: first guess is a (simple?) substitution cipher because there are multiple identical words in there like `vF` is 5 times in there so probably a common word like "is" or "of"

Comment: Are the double spaces in the markdown relevant?

Comment: @Sleafar The double spaces, it turns out, were dashes that were removed and left a space on each side. I didn't catch it in my conversion. Well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is

> Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation conceived in liberty and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal now we are engaged in a great civil war testing whether that nation or any nation so conceived and so dedicated can long endure we are met on a great battlefield of that war we have come to dedicate a portion of that field as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live it is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this but in a larger sense we can not dedicate we can not consecrate we can not hallow this ground the brave men living and dead who struggled here have consecrated it far above our poor power to add or detract the world will little note nor long remember what we say here but it can never forget what they did here it is for us the living rather to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advancedit is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain that this nation under god shall have a new birth of freedom and that government of the people by the people for the people shall not perish from the earth

To solve follow this rules

Rule 1:

> if small letter, get the next letter. In case of z, go back to a

Rule 2:

> if capital letter, go back to the previous letter

Thanks DrunkWolf for faster conversion, it takes time for manual conversion lol

Comment: It's exactly the same as the Gettysburg Address (without punctuation), but missing one space between the words "advanced" and "it".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qx5mwmy7/ decodes it fully